# Return every second item from a list with Underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'd like to return every second item from a list, using Underscore.

I guess I could do something like this:

```
var i = 0;
_.filter([1,2,3,4...], function(item) { 
  i++;
  return (i%2 == 0);
});
```

but is there a more elegant way, native to Underscore?

Comment: No need for underscore here... you can simply do `[1,2,3,4...].filter(function(_,i){ return i%2;})` it's fully supported inall non-really-ancient browsers (yes, even IE9).

Comment: i would suggest using function takeEveryN(item, index) {return index % this == 0;}; and calling it like _.filter([1,2,3,4], takeEveryN, 2); so you can hop over different numbers of items later...

Comment: @dandavis that's confusing since there already is an `Array.prototype.every` that does something else.

Comment: mine's not an [] prop, but i'll concede the point and edit my comment to remove ambiguity. good input. my main point was to use a named function because it encourages reuse and defining functions closer to global makes the code faster to run in V8 if not elsewhere since it doesn't re-parse the function as much...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function which is getting called by [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) will get the current index as well, as the second parameter and you can make use of that like this

```
console.log(_.filter([1, 2, 3, 4], function(item, index) {
    return index % 2 == 0;
}));
# [ 1, 3 ]
```

Since you want to start from the second element, you just have to change the condition a little, like this

```
console.log(_.filter([1, 2, 3, 4], function(item, index) {
    return index % 2 == 1;
}));
# [ 2, 4 ]
```

Alternatively, you can use the native [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in the same way, like this

```
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4].filter(function(item, index) {
    return index % 2 == 1;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_.filter([1,2,3,4...], function(item, index) { 
  return (index % 2 == 0);
});
```

`filter` predicate accepts two parameters - item value and index value.

Comment: three params actually, don't forget about the collection... four if you count "this"...

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = [1,2,3,4];
var tt = _.first(_.rest([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]));
console.log(tt);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nr5jg/)